# How can I get a single integer from an array?

Tags: arrays, integer

For example, I have an array of two chars:

```
char myArr[2] = {5, 1};
```

Is there any way to get a single integer (51) which is linked of two of these numbers?

Comment: `myArr[2][0]` would give you five. `myArr[2][1]` would give you 1. `myArr[2]` returns that array `{5,1}` So, if we gave that array a name, say `x`, then we could access its elements with `x[0]`  and `x[1]`, right? Well, you're just skipping the naming part. `myArr[2]` <--- the array, so `myArr[2][0]` is the first element in that array.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the numeric representation of a possible combination of array indices? You can use string concatenation to create a single string from the array like either

`string s = new string(myArr);`

or

```
string s = String.Concat( myArr );
```

Then you could do an int parse or convert on the string to give you the numeric representation of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this snippet of code

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        char myArr[] = {5, 1};
        int val=0;
        for(int i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){
            val=val*10+myArr[i];
        }
        System.out.println(val);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `char` array with `int` values, then the easiest way is to multiply each element of the array by **10**, so you can sum the next char value to the **tens** that were multiplied. This will allow you to join each element of your char array, for example:

```
private static int TEN_UNITS = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char input[] = {5, 9, 4, 1, 0, 8};
    int result = joinIntChars(input);
    System.out.println("Single integer: " + result);
}

private static int joinIntChars(char[] myArr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (char c : myArr) {
        sum = (sum * TEN_UNITS); // each element of the array is multiplied by 10
        sum += c; // now this will sum the next char value to the previous result
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Single integer: 594108
```